# How to implement dynamic types in a bytecode interpreter?

Tags: interpreter, dynamic-typing

I'm making a bytecode interpreter for a dinamically typed language. For example this expression:

```
2 + 3
```

Would create the following assembly-like output (later compiled to bytecode):

```
iconst reg1, 2 ; Put integer 2 to register 1
iconst reg2, 3 ; Put integer 3 to register 2
iadd reg3, reg1, reg2 ; Add the 2 as integers from reg1 and 2 and put it into reg3
```

Another example would be:

```
1 + 3.2
```

Output:

```
iconst reg1, 1
itof reg2, reg1 ; Convert integer to float and put it into reg2
fconst reg3, reg2
fadd reg4, reg2, reg3
```

So every type has it's own operator (fadd, iadd, maybe sadd...). That means I need to know the types at compile type. That's not a problem until I have for example a function call:

```
function foo(x, y):
    return x + y
```

foo() could be called with integers, floats, even mixed. So I can't generate the correct bytecode for it at compile-time. What would be the best to do, so it won't really affect the speed. Is it a good strategy to generate the function with the type of parameters that are used? So if this gets called:

```
foo(2, 3.2)
```

It would generate something like foo@int,float(). Or is it better to resolve it at runtime? Can I do that without really affecting the performance? How? How does lua do it?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, maybe I'll need to work on my googling skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of several ways to handle this:

**1 -** keep track of how foo(x, y) is called, and log the different function signature(s). This can get complicated, as foo(x, y) may get called from bar(a, b), and bar(a, b) might get called from baz(c, d), and so on.

After you have parsed the entire program, built your AST, and traversed it to log all the unique signatures of calls to foo(x, y), generate code for the different ways it was called.

You might have:

```
foo(int, int)
foo(float, int)
```

This tells you that you'll need two unique foo(x, y) functions.

**2 -** Change you opcode set to have generic add, sub, mul etc. opcodes.  Then the generic opcodes would have to determine the type of their operands at runtime and perform appropriately. This would be somewhat slower, as the opcodes now have to inspect the operands as to their type, and branch based on that.

**3 -** As you surmised, don't generate the code for functions until they are actually called.  This would be a little slower, but only on the first invocation of said function.  As in (1), you will still need to support multiple unique function signatures, so some bookkeeping will still be necessary.

I hope this helps!